# Is there any difference between del and pop for column in python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, del

I have just learned how to work with DataFrame in python's Pandas through an online course and there is this question:

"What is the difference between deleting and popping column?"

I thought they work the same way but most of the answers are 
"You can store a popped column"

What does that mean?
I saw from the documentation and it tells me that there's only a deleting a single column use out of the pop function so Im kind of confused here

Comment: `del` doesn't return what was deleted back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between deleting and popping a column is that pop will return the deleted column back to you while del method won't.